# I need to integrate in app purchase in already available app. I added product in iTunes but that product status is "Waiting for review"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I need to integrate in app purchase in already available app. I added product in iTunes but that product status is "Waiting for review". How can I test with these products in device using developer certificates?

Comment: read the itunes in app purchase guide

Comment: did u took screen shot?