# in app purchase ios with "Waiting For Review" state

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Can I access in app product which is in state of "Waiting For Review". I added product in itunes store. but it is not accessible in my ios project.

Comment: how is this question different to your previous question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to integrate in app purchase in already available app. I added product in iTunes but that product status is "Waiting for review"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268269/i-need-to-integrate-in-app-purchase-in-already-available-app-i-added-product-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can access insandbox mode through app id.